# PayPal Android SDK peer-to-peer payment

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Backstory/Use case:**

I am developing an Android application for managing group payments as a school project

**My problem:**

I want to use the PayPal Android SDK to pay to an email address in much the same way that you can pay to an email address from paypal.com. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this with the PayPal SDK. Everything seems designed for payments to go directly to a vendor. Is it even possible to pay directly to an email address using the Android SDK?

Comment: I'm looking for an same thing. Did you solved it?

Comment: **Short Answer:** Nope. It's just not possible with the Android SDK. They even say so in their documentation.
**Long Answer:** I eventually ended up using the legacy MPL. I don't know what StackOverflow's rules are about self promotion but  here is a link to my github repo with my implementation. https://github.com/jbccollins/CMSC436-PayPal-MPL-Demo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/housecore/housecore I also made a class presentation with slides comparing the MPL to the SDK and explaining how to use the MPL. It's not on github right now but if you'd like I can put it up.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I actually filed an issue on their Android SDK here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/326
Their answer is that P2P payments is for partners only, I'm trying to reach their sales. It's pain.

Does your solution work with no fees? I was using MPL a year ago. It worked with no fees for some time and they then suddenly started charging fees.